# Cannot run MongoDB code through Python evnoy

Tags: python, mongodb, python-envoy

I am trying to import data into MongoDB through Python envoy. However it keeps showing "permission denied". After I have changed the permission of the data file, it keeps showing "Exec format error".

However, when I ran the same command on MongoDB Shell, everything works well.

Do you know how can I run the commands through Python envoy?

Below is my code:

```
def load_data():
    data_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'enron.mbox.json')
    print data_file

    r = envoy.run('mongoimport --db enron --collection mbox --drop --file %s' % data_file)
    print r.std_out
    print sys.stderr.write(r.std_err)
```

Comment: hey what do you mean by `--drop` ?

Comment: `--drop` drops an existing collection with the same name before importing

Comment: The tutorial here is using "--drop": https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/import-data/      I'm totally new to MongoDB... But I was using this command in the shell and it works   @NikhilParmar

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun ok thanks ;)

Comment: @CherryWu I just ran - `def load_data():
    r = envoy.run('mongoimport --db test --collection ff --drop --file complaints.json')
    print r.std_out

load_data()`                      It is running fine and importing

Comment: Thank you @NikhilParmar  I tried this too... it still shows the same error. I guess it's because some settings on my Mac should be changed, like file executable or permission, but I changed what I could, still have the error...

Comment: @CherryWu may be giving permission to file like `chmod`

Comment: @CherryWu sorry I don't know much about mac